# Adicionar configuração pessoal: Mostrar imagens/Thumbnails

Tags: novo-recurso, chat

Sugiro a adição de um item de configuração pessoal: "Mostrar imagens/Thumbnails". Quando desligado, imagens adicionadas ao chat apareceriam apenas como links ao invés de ter seu sua miniatura renderizada.

Uma variante desta solução seria criar uma função *clientside-only*, "Limpar imagens do chat", que simplesmente executaria o seguinte script:

```
javascript:$("div.ob-image").remove();
```

removendo assim todas as imagens.

Update - Pequeno script para TamperMonkey/GreaseMonkey demonstrando o script client-side:
http://pastebin.com/6UFCAXht

Este script adiciona dois botões à barra lateral:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Changelog:

6/25/2015 - Inclui remoção de vídeos e mensagens de sistema (thx Jorge B.), compatibilidade com Firefox/GreaseMonkey,

Comment: Boa, mas como é uma feature do chat e não do SOpt seria melhor abrir no meta.SE, não?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Não precisa, isso pode ser discutido aqui, e o Gabe encaminha o assunto internamente.

Comment: Aparentemente o Ricardo Henrique tem causado problemas para o OnoSendai no trabalho :P

Comment: @Math na verdade eu faço spam de imagens também de vez em quando. Não quero prejudica o ambiente profissional de ninguém ,então estou propondo isso. =)

Comment: Tá certo. Por várias vezes eu já quis dar um `cls` na minha tela porque tinha uma imagem que não combinava muito com um ambiente sério de trabalho.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Eu quis enfatizar que assuntos da rede podem sim ser tratados aqui. Agora, se preferirem tratar no MSE, ou fazer cross-post em ambos os metas, fiquem à vontade.

Comment: @Math Se você colar o snippet JS que eu mencionei no corpo da proposta diretamente na barra de navegação do browser, as imagens somem. =)

Comment: @OnoSendai Ao invés de JS poderia injetar um CSS com `display: none` -- com aquela extensão Monkeyjs (eu não lembro o nome)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento também funciona! Mas seria interessante algo que não tivesse dependências externas.

Comment: Acredito ser algo bem útil, quem sabe eles até implementam em todos os chats do SE. Apoiado também. Simples e eficaz. :)

Comment: Sensacional!​​​

Comment: Poderíamos atualizar o link para a versão do github e remover o pastebin, fora isto gostaria de lhe pedir para postar no http://stackapps.com para que assim possa divulgar o script entre qualquer comunidade da SE.

Answer (score 12):

Dou meu total apoio a esta proposta.

Uma ou duas vezes já tive que fechar rapidamente o bate-papo por ter um conteúdo não tão apropriado para um ambiente de trabalho mais sério.

Além de evitar mal-entendidos, fará com que mais gente possa acessar o site sem receios mesmo com pessoas ao redor.

Answer (score 6):

Ao invés de remover a imagem você pode rodar um script que coloca uma imagem tipo essa no lugar das demais imagens: [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esse script faz isso:

```
javascript:$("div.ob-image > a > img").attr('src', 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/r7hup.png');
```

As vezes essa ideia é interessante para você entender o contexto da conversa. Você não precisa saber exatamente qual imagem estava ali, mas saberá que tinha algo ali que foi substituído.

Só falta agora descobrirmos um jeito simples de chamar esse script enquanto a SE não implementa a ideia de forma oficial.

Comment: Obrigado pela sugestão, eu modifiquei um pouco sua sugestão e adicionei ao script (substituindo o texto por 'Image Deleted', para focar parecida com a mensagem padrão de quando um texto é deletado pelo usuário. Danke!

Comment: Ficou sensacional sua solução, já testei. Valeu!

Answer (score 1):

notei que a versão do pastebin está bem diferente do github, inicialmente eu tinha feito isto:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         SO ClearChat
// @namespace    com.onosendai
// @version      0.3.2
// @author       OnoSendai
// @match        http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11910/estouro-de-pilha
// @grant        none
// @run-at       document-start
// ==/UserScript==

setTimeout(function(){
    console.log('Hooking up!');

    $(function(){
        var r = $(
                 '<br/>'+
                 '<a id="clsBtn" class="tag" href="javascript:void(0);">Limpar Chat</a>' +
                 '<a id="clsiBtn" class="tag" href="javascript:void(0);">Remover Imagens/Videos</a>'
                 );

        $("#room-tags").append(r);

        $("#clsBtn").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            $("div.system-message, div.monologue").remove();
        });

        $("#clsiBtn").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            $("div.ob-image > a").addClass('deleted').text('(Image removed)');
            $("div.ob-youtube > a").addClass('deleted').text('(Video removed)');
        });
    });
}, 1000);
```

Pretendia enviar ao github, mas notei que lá esta bem diferente, todavia vou explicar as mudanças aqui:

1. Tinha uma variável chamada `event`, mas ela era indefinida, no caso o evento estava como variável `e`, então corrigi.
2. `div.system-message` e `div.monologue` estavam em objetos diferentes, então eu juntei ambos em `$("div.system-message, div.monologue").remove();`
3. Adicionei `href=""`, pois apesar de não ter certeza, acredito que sem o href alguns navegadores podem não entender bem o link, talvez tab, ou até touch de tablets e smarthphones.

Então após notar o github, eu mandei um pull-request: https://github.com/lbotinelly/SOClearChat/pull/2

- Na primeira atualização o principal motivo foi trocar `DOMNodeInserted` ([obsoleto <sup>MDN</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Mutation_events)) por `MutationObserver`
- No segundo update eu notei que se as imagens favoritadas (com estrela) estiverem muito abaixo elas ficam cortadas, e o fundo branco eventualmente se confunde, então troquei `top` por `bottom` e adicionei `box-shadow`.

  Antes:

  > [image: thumb no chat]

  Depois:

  > [image: Após o update]