# Tem como manter a aba "Participação" fixa quando entro no perfil dos usuários?

Tags: suporte, perfil

No meu perfil eu entro e está sempre nesta aba que é mais útil pra mim. Mas quando entro no perfil dos usuário tenho sempre que trocar a aba.

Pra falar a verdade, não gostei desta forma, está mais trabalhoso. Mesmo deixando fixo nesta aba ainda preciso mudar de vez em quando porque tem coisa relevantes na outra. Isso não prejudica tanto mas ter que trocar de aba quase todas as vezes é bem chato.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Olhando na [resposta linkada](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260663/show-me-some-activity) pelo @bfavaretto, vi que existe uma possibilidade de se resolver o problema em questão pelo lado do cliente. E dessa vez não foi desenvolvida nem pelo [OnoSendai](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3977/3117) nem pelo [Guilherme Nascimento](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4075/3117) :)

É um script que disponibilizaram no Stack Apps para resolver justamente isso:

['Activity' tab on profile as default](https://stackapps.com/q/6267/29568)

Para quem não gosta de clicar em links, aí vai o script completo:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        'Activity' tab as default
// @namespace   http://stackexchange.com/users/3094403/programfox
// @author      ProgramFOX
// @description A userscript that automatically shows the Activity tab as default on profile pages
// @match       *://*.stackexchange.com/users/*
// @match       *://*.stackoverflow.com/users/*
// @match       *://*.superuser.com/users/*
// @match       *://*.serverfault.com/users/*
// @match       *://*.askubuntu.com/users/*
// @match       *://*.mathoverflow.net/users/*
// @match       *://*.stackapps.com/users/*
// @version     1.3
// @grant       none
// @run-at      document-start
// ==/UserScript==

if (!window.location.search &&
    !window.location.hash &&
    !(/\/users\/edit\/|\/login\b/i).test(window.location.pathname)) {
    window.location.replace(window.location.href + "?tab=topactivity");
}
```

Comment: Para quem for usar, ele atrasa o render da página.

Comment: Sim, eu percebi isso. Gostaria um jeito de deixar mais natural mas ainda não parei para ver se é possível.

Answer (score 8):

Não tem como, isso é *by-design* do novo layout. A menos que você seja moderador, aí todos os perfis sempre abrem na aba *participação* ;)

Já existe um pedido de alteração disso no MSE, por enquanto sem resposta oficial: *[Show me some activity](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260663/show-me-some-activity)*.

Comment: Então quero novas eleições :D

Comment: Golpista! Coxinha! :D

Comment: @bigown ahahahahah

Comment: Melhor privilégio que há por ser moderador :) Acho que a aba "Perfil" poderia ser mostrada para não-membros da comunidade, enquanto para todos os usuários mostrasse a "Participação".

Comment: @Math Ou talvez chavear isso com base em alguma métrica que mostre que a pessoa tem interesse em moderação comunitária, como presença de determinada(s) medalha(s).

Comment: Exato. Ou por reputação, que nem os avisos de medalhas que deixam de ser mostradas devido a algum critério ou outros avisos que [também param de aparecer](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2257/3117) pelo mesmo motivo.